# Обновление страницы через заданный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript

Мне нужен скрипт, обновляющий страницу через заданный промежуток времени при условии бездействия клиента. Т.е. таймер сбрасывается при клике или нажатии клавиши на клавиатуре.
Или таймер, через промежуток которого также обновляется страничка, только при нажатии на кнопку (которых может быть несколько) счетчик останавливался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю зачем Вам это нужно, но вот один из возможных вариантов именно только для кликов и для нажатий клавиш на клавиатуре.

```
var timeReload = 1;//время в минутах
timeReload = timeReload*60;
var timenow=0;

    function isReload()
    {
    timenow++;
    if (timenow>=timeReload) {
    timenow=0;

    document.location.reload();
    }
    }

    var t=setInterval("isReload()",1000);

        function MyEvent(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
         timenow=0;

        }

        document.onclick = MyEvent;//клик
        document.onkeypress = MyEvent;//нажатие клавиш клавиатуры

    </script>
<body> <button onClick='clearInterval(t)'>stop</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Если можете, то напишите, как вообще отключить это обновление после oneclick на каком либо объекте (кнопке (input, button))

Comment: Уже добавил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. 
Все начало работать!!!
Спасибо, спасибо, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = false;
var reloadTime = 5000; // ms

function reloadTimer() {
  if (!!timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){ top.location.reload(); }, reloadTime);
  }
```

И далее

```
<input type="button" onclick="reloadTimer()" value="Перезапустить" />
```

Можно еще так, тогда будет близко  первому варианту:

```
document.onmousemove = reloadTimer;
```

Comment: Это второй вариант?

Comment: Да, второй. Сделать перегрузку по *любому* действию проблематично - по идее, надо обработчики вешать либо на все поля ввода, кнопки и ссылки(учитываем tag-навигацию), либо на документ. 

Возможно, сработает 

    document.onkeypress=reloadTimer;